# How can I Query a Knowledge Graph?

Tags: knowledge-representation

One approach for querying knowledge graph is to use nearest neighbor (NN) data structures. Read the paper [On Integrating Knowledge Graph Embedding into SPARQL Query Processing](https://sanghyun-hong.github.io/docs/papers/Hong_KGENN.pdf) for more details. Roughly speaking, the authors redesign the loss function used for knowledge graph embedding methods to generate vector representations that improve the NN search performance. For example:

[image]

Nonetheless, the following fact is know:

> It is known that using the same embedding space to represent both entities and relations is **less competitive** compared to considering two separate spaces. (source: [LogicENN: A Neural Based Knowledge Graphs Embedding Model with Logical Rules](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07141.pdf)).

My question is: Since there are embedding which represent entities and relations in different spaces, how can I use NN methods to ask a Knowledge Graph?